# translateZ(0) could enable an acceleration of GPU in Chrome,but it could work in other browser?

Tags: google-chrome, gpu

Recently I read a hack about `translateZ(0)`, it is said that by using this property, it could enable an acceleration of GPU

but it is only work in Chrome or webkit browser, or could work in IE and firefox, too?

Answer (score 1):

well it's actually a webkit hack (basically abusing the way webkit treats `translateZ`)

Answer (score 0):

Webkit only using `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);` or `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

`will-change` allows an author to inform the UA ahead of time of what kinds of changes they are likely to make to an element. This allows the UA to optimize how they handle the element ahead of time, performing potentially-expensive work preparing for an animation before the animation actually begins.

[W3C: CSS Will Change](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/)

[Browser support for will-change property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change)